# Java Session ID Not Found in Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I've got a Java issue that has been baffling me. Below is my quick explanation of the flow of this web app.

1. A user clicks a button on a jsp page which calls the server
2. The server code "ManagerWebsiteFlow.java" performs some logic and puts some data in the request session attribute
3. The control is then passed on to an "output.jsp" page
4. The output.jsp page contains an html image tag
5. The html image tag calls the server "ManagerStreamReport.java", this class creates a png & returns it to the image tag.

This all works fine in my local environment with the four major browsers. 
But when the code is online, it does not work in FF and Chrome. The session attribute is lost during step 5.

Extra information. In both FF and Chrome, if I go back to step 1 and try again, it all works fine & there are no session lost issues. And it continues working fine until I close the browser and start again.

I'm using Tomcat 7, Java 7 and Spring MVC version 4.
The major pieces of my code are below along with some log tracing where you can see how the session ID is lost in FF and Chrome and not in IE and Safari.

Is it a timing issue? Why would FF and Chrome be the only ones that don't work? 
Any thing ideas as to what is causing this? Any suggestions on how to fix or what else I could check?

```
ManagerWebsiteFlow {
    public String build(HttpServletRequest request) {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("MyObjectName", "MyContent"); 
        log.error("MWF The Session ID Is : " + request.getSession().getId());
        // More code here
    }
}


<!-- output.jsp -->
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="http://www.onlinewebsite.com/streamReport.do" id="mainImg" /> 
    </body>
</html>

ManagerStreamReport{
    public boolean convertChart(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        log.error("MCC The Session ID Is : " + request.getSession().getId());
        // More code here
    }
}


*** LOG4J File **

-- Logging when using Chrome
10-14@20:56:13 ERROR (ManagerWebsiteFlow.java:51)     - MWF The Session ID Is : 9804070CF5C01EB1B8DA4690158A9E2B
10-14@20:56:13 ERROR (ManagerStreamReport.java:34)    - MSC The Session ID Is : 699645602C235EE27D829DAAEBF7DF55

-- Logging when using FF
10-14@20:55:26 ERROR (ManagerWebsiteFlow.java:51)     - MWF The Session ID Is : 7DB390D949399B26AFAB5D4071872738
10-14@20:55:26 ERROR (ManagerStreamReport.java:34)    - MSC The Session ID Is : B078DB4F3B3B55A03477E12972AC617A

-- Logging when using IE
10-14@20:57:04 ERROR (ManagerWebsiteFlow.java:51)     - MWF The Session ID Is : B344BEDE232C7574332A55C0D28D2561
10-14@20:57:05 ERROR (ManagerStreamReport.java:34)    - MSC The Session ID Is : B344BEDE232C7574332A55C0D28D2561

-- Logging when using Safari
10-14@20:57:50 ERROR (ManagerWebsiteFlow.java:51)     - MWF The Session ID Is : FB8B892E5E20049421BA185EEC3B3FAA
10-14@20:57:51 ERROR (ManagerStreamReport.java:34)    - MSC The Session ID Is : FB8B892E5E20049421BA185EEC3B3FAA
```

Comment: Is there SSL involved here?

Comment: @Elliott Frisch 
Nope, no ssl.

Comment: Have you checked under the network tab in the developer tools in FF or Chrome?

Comment: Do you have a LoadBalancer or more than one Tomcat in replication in the online version?

Comment: @ElliotFrich
I checked the Network tabs and it does not thing spcecial. It shows the image html tag calling the server to retrieve the image.

Comment: @Master Slave
No LoadBalancer and no replication on tomcat local or prod. Just a traightforwad simple webapp. I thought perhaps it was the session tracking (I'm grasping at straws I know) so I put the below value but no difference. 

<session-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes accross this in the future, here is the solution to my issue. The html image tag is using "http://www.onlinewebsite.com" but when I entered the website, I was using  "onlinewebsite.com". So no existing session was found for the "different" domain.

To avoid this issue, the two following attributes were required in the server.xml context :

```
sessionCookiePath="/" 
sessionCookieDomain=".onlinewebsite.com">
```

This worked for tomcat 7.